# How to get file owner name?

Tags: windows, perl

Is there a perl script to add owner's/authors name of the file?

Comment: Do you mean the perl file itself, or some other document?

Comment: Are you looking for a script, that will add file's owner name into the file. Or an automatic way to add script author name into the script?

Comment: ya...midson...that is what i want... for example if i read ab.java.. i should be able to get author/owner name of it n also to insert the information got their...

Answer (score 7):

```
my $owner = getpwuid((stat($file))[4]);
```

see [stat](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/stat.html) and [getpwuid](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/getpwuid.html) for more detail.

**Update:** for Windows,

from this post: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=865219

```
use Win32::OLE;
  my $objShell = Win32::OLE->CreateObject("Shell.Application");
  my $objFolder=$objShell->Namespace("c:\\a") or die "$!" ;
  my $a = $objFolder->ParseName("a.txt")  or die "$!" ;
  print $objFolder->GetDetailsOf($a, 8) or die "$!" ;
```

or,

```
 use Win32::Perms;
 my $username = Win32::Perms->new($filename)->Owner;
```

Comment: Hi nikhil..if i use the above script i am getting "The getpwuid function is unimplemented at time.pl"as error

Comment: are you working on Windows because getpwuid is a *NIX/POSIX-ism.

Comment: nikhil....error persists "Can't locate object method "new" via package "Win32::Perms""

Comment: you cannot used it directly, you have to installed `Win32::Perms` first and then used it.

Comment: On Perl 5.16, I had to use index 10 (instead of 8) to get the owner. [Folder.GetDetailsOf()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787870(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

my @sb = stat "/etc/passwd";
my $userid = $sb[4];
my @pwent = getpwuid $userid;
my $username = $pwent[0];

print "/etc/passwd is owned by $username\n";


$ /tmp/foo.pl 
/etc/passwd is owned by root
```

The `perldoc perlfunc` guide has lots of information on these families of functions.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. The output is /etc/passwd is owned by User::pwent=ARRAY(0x8351f38)

Comment: @LoveRight, can you pastebin what you're doing? I just tried this again and it still works on much newer Perl... or perhaps start a new question with your code, that might get a faster response..

Comment: @LoveRight, you use 'User::pwent', try don't 'use' it or call getpwuid like this: `CORE::getpwuid $userid;`
This solve my problem with 'User::pwent=ARRAY(0x8351f38' output.